# Get logged in user from node loaded with node_view

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a specific content type with it's own node template. When I go directly to the node all user information from the `$user` variable is accessible. However when I load this node with node_view into another page any of the code in the template that is dependent upon the user info breaks because the template doesn't register the user as logged in. Is there something special I need to do to make it properly populate the $user variable?

### Edit

This is at the top of my node--product.tpl.php (the node template I'm loading).

```
 global $user;
 print_r($user);
```

This returns:

```
stdClass Object ( [uid] => 0 [hostname] => ###.###.###.### [roles] => Array ( [1] => anonymous user ) [cache] => 0 )
```

Comment: Have you checked $GLOBALS['user']?

Comment: yes. a `print_r` of it returns: `stdClass Object ( [uid] => 0 [hostname] => ###.###.###.### [roles] => Array ( [1] => anonymous user ) [cache] => 0 )`

Comment: `global $user;`?

Comment: returns same thing.

Comment: You are accessing page as anonymous user that's the reason it displays above output.. global $user; will get the logged in user details..

Comment: I'm not though. I'm logged in as an admin in fact. I see the admin toobar at the top. global $user returns the same output.

Comment: As a reminder if I go directly to the node as a page it works. It's only if I use drupal_render(node_view()) to load this view into another page that I have this problem.